# What is more valuable: PhD degree or journal publication?

Tags: phd, united-kingdom, europe

Suppose, Mr 'X' has a MSc plus 3y PhD degree and only 2 journal publications.

On the other hand, Mr 'Y' has only an MSc degree and 6  journal publications, 3 text books written, and 3 professional books written.

A university/college calls for applications for a position of lecturer or assistant professor, and these two guys apply.

If all other factors are same, who is more likely to get a position?

Comment: If there is a strict minimum requirement of a PhD, the second candidate may not be considered at all.

Comment: Depends on whether the second guy will obtain a PhD in the foreseeable future (a few months) or not.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper, What if '***Yes***', and what if '***No***'?

Comment: If "no", it would probably not be possible to hire him (in most countries I know, I'm EU-based). If "yes", they can probably hire him under the condition that he will complete the PhD in a certain timeframe. Then he might be the preferred choice.

Comment: If we ignore the formal requirements or assume they can be bent, it really depends on the content publications, whether it is a solo-author publication, what are the contributions of each author; the number is not much important

Comment: @onurcanbektas "the number is not much important" I tend to disagree. It's surely not the only criterion that matters, but from the perspective of the hiring committee, a candidate with more publications might be the safer choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to specify which country/system/subject you are talking about.

In the UK a PhD is pretty much a 100% requirement in most subjects. The only exceptions to this are subject where you would be doing vocational training, such as business studies, management, nursing, perhaps even law(?) where an exceptional standing and experience in the field might make up for a lack of PhD. The other big exception is medical school, where you could have an MD rather than a PhD.

Comment: *You will have to specify which country/system/subject you are talking about.* --- UK and Portugal.

Comment: In essense I agree, and these days a PhD is very often a formal requirement. Vocational training is quite broad, but yes, in many cases a visiting "teacher/ researcher" with strong industry background can be selected. Few such people have publications etc but hey fall in different category. Also, at least in times past, in Oxbridge some stellar PhD candidates and future renowned academics were given lecturships before completing a PhD and remained Mr/Mrs throughout their career - a peculiar badge of honour. I do not know if that happens these days.